# Что обязан знать Junior .NET developer?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#

Что обязан знать Junior .NET developer?

Comment: посмотрите [Programmer Competency Matrix][1]


  [1]: http://www.starling-software.com/employment/programmer-competency-matrix.html

Answer (score 5):

Junior обязан знать .Net Framework на достаточном для старта уровне, но необязательно должен иметь опыт реальной разработки. В случае, если вы хотите устроится джуниором по асп, то скорее всего вам нужны будут знания .net 3-4, базовые знания asp.net forms, лучше MVC 2-3, html/css + крайне желательно javascript(jQuery), AJAX. Базы данных, как минимум MS SQL на уровне создания структуры базы, построения запросов. ADO.Net, Entity Framework для работы с базой.

Comment: спасибо,а конкретно что по ASP.NET не подскажите?

Comment: AJAX ASP.NET подойдёт или на более низком уровне,типа Callback'а?

Comment: Конкретно по asp.net я бы советовал забить на изучение web forms и начать изучать сразу asp.net mvc 2-3, хорошие видеоуроки есть прям на оф. сайте http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 2):

[What Great NET Developers Ought To Know](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx)  раздел "Everyone who writes code" а желательно и раздел "Mid-Level .NET Developer"

Answer (score 0):

Junior должен уметь работать с Debug инструментами.